# Pivot function with out aggregation using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, pivot

I have below of an example input and output.

```
Step_Name  Parameter_name  Step  Value  Substep  
 Test 1        Param 1       1     #       1
 Test 1        Param 2       1     #       1
 Test 1        Param 3       1     #       1
 Test 1        Param 1       1     #       2
 Test 1        Param 2       1     #       2
 Test 1        Param 3       1     #       2
 Test 2        Param 1       2     #       1
 Test 2        Param 2       2     #       1
 Test 2        Param 3       2     #       1
 Test 2        Param 1       2     #       2
 Test 2        Param 2       2     #       2
 Test 2        Param 3       2     #       2
```

The desired out put I want is...

```
Step Step_name  SubStep  Param 1  Param 2  Param 3
  1   Test 1       1        #        #        #
  1   Test 1       2        #        #        #
  2   Test 2       1        #        #        #
  2   Test 2       2        #        #        #
```

I am able to currently do this in pandas using this command:

```
df.pivot_table(index = ["Step", "Step_name", "SubStep","Filename"], columns = 'Parameter_name', values = 'Value').reset_index()
```

When I try to do this in PySpark I use this:

```
df.groupBy("Step", "Step_name", "SubStep", "Filename").pivot("Parameter_name")
```

However, this returns an object and I am required to use an aggregation function like a sum. How do I avoid doing this?

Comment: use `first` as the aggregation.

Comment: What would the syntax be then adding .first() ?

Answer (score 0):

@Canadian-Hombre

You can't avoid this.
What you can do is using the first to take the first element from each which will mimick the current state of the table view.

```
df.groupBy("Step", "Step_name", "SubStep", "Filename").pivot("Parameter_name").agg(F.first("Param 1"), F.first("Param 2")..)
```